Realm Database Dependency Issue
For my android app, I am trying to use Realm's NoSQL embedded database to store files locally as well as on the cloud. However, most of the documentation that I look up seems to be for Kotlin-based apps, whereas I am doing a Java-based app. Can someone point as to how I should configure my build.gradle.kts dependencies, as well as include these dependencies in my libs.versions.toml file? So far, I have this in my build.gradle.kts on the app level:
dependencies 
{
  implementation(libs.realm.gradle.plugin)
}

In my libs.versions.toml file, I have added the following lines:
[versions]
realmGradlePlugin = "10.19.0"

[libraries]
realm-gradle-plugin = { module = "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "realmGradlePlugin" }

Whenever I try extending the "RealmObject" class, however, it doesn't seem to work, which means I messed up somewhere in my dependency configuration. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is documentation for Configuring Realm for Java however, note that it is Maintenance Mode and it's strongly suggested to work with Kotlin.
